# Java Util Timer in a Button

Tags: java, button, timer

I am working on a board game, and in a part of the game, I need to have like this button which is when clicked, will change a label repeatedly counting 1 to 5 with 1 second delay interval, and after will change the label into "done", but the problem it changes the label into "done" first then the counting.

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                // @Override
                public void run() {
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 6) {
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                        return;
                    }
                    lbl.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            }, 1000,1000);
            lbl.setText("done");
        }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the button, the actionPerformed() method is executed sequentially:

1. Create a new timer
2. Register a task to execute regularly each second, **in the future**
3. Set the button label to "Done"

Then, later, the timer do its job and will start to increase the variable count, updating each time the button label. Reading like this should help you to understand what is happening: the timer is executed in a separate thread. timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() is a non-blocking function, which registers a TimerTask to execute later, and returns immediately.

To fix your issue, something like that could be a solution:

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                // @Override
                public void run() {
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 6) {
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();

                        // We set the label to done only when the counter
                        // reaches the value 6, after button displayed 5
                        lbl.setText("done");

                        return;
                    }
                    lbl.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            }, 1000,1000);
        }});
```